# what makes a digraph transitive?

Tags: graph-theory, relations

Draw a digraph of a transitive tournament on 5 teams.

What i drew was a pentagon and a star in the middle and made it transitive but doesn't that just contradicts the winning team? like 1 beat 2 , 2 beat 3 etc meaning 1 beats itself?

Comment: transitivity would hold if for all $x, y, z \in \{a, b, c, d, e\},$ if $x$ beats $y$ and $y$ beats $z$, then $x$ beats $z$.

Comment: If in fact the relation is transitive, and team 1 beats team 2, and team 2 beats team 3, we need to have that team 1 beats team 3.

Comment: Given your description of the pentagon (5 vertices) such that all vertices connect with the reaming four, (a pentagon connected via the pentagon and 5 point star, then the relation is indeed transitive.  I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your graph to be transitive, it must be possible to number the vertices $1,2,3,4$, and $5$ in such a way that if $1\le k<\ell\le 5$, the edge between vertex $k$ and vertex $\ell$ is directed from $k$ to $\ell$. If you can do that, your graph is correct. There is no circularity: $1$ beats $2$, $2$ beats $3$, $3$ beats $4$, and $4$ beats $5$, but $5$ loses to everyone else, and no one beats $1$. $1$ is the winner; $2$ beats everyone except $1$; $3$ beats everyone except $1$ and $2$; $4$ beats only $5$; and $5$ loses to everyone else.

Comment: ahhh okay so i made a last mistake making it into a cycle where 5 beats 1  its the other way around? or do we not connect 1   and 5?

Comment: @darkflames363: There is an edge from $1$ to $5$, but not from $5$ to $1$.

Comment: thank you so much that clarifies it.  i was wonder how can you beat yourself !

Comment: @darkflames363: You’re very welcome.